# Formatting Decimal with SQL

Tags: sql, casting, number-formatting

How can I format a number like 0731 to 07.31 and keeping the leading 0.
I was running this query, it works but it removes the leading 0 that I want to keep.

```
CAST(CAST(proc_P AS decimal(4,0))/100 AS Decimal(4,2))
```

Comment: What implementation of sql are you using? Each probably has its own string formatting functions

Comment: Is it varchar type? does it always have 4 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
select proc_P,RIGHT('000'+CAST(CAST((CAST(proc_P as decimal(4,0))/100) as decimal(4,2)) as VARCHAR(5)),5)
from test
```

SQLFiddle:   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69b09/13

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `proc_P` is a varchar (having leading 0), try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(proc_P, LEN(proc_P) - 2) + '.' + RIGHT(proc_P,2)
```

Comment: Not it doesn't have a leading zero. Sparky's answer solved the problem